# can't access firstViewController Var. from appdelegate, after swapping between first and second ViewController. with that phantom situation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, appdelegate

At the moment I do have two ViewControllers, separate files! first as a main interface and second as a setting panel! on a first view I have a button, and a label on it.

mission is , to change**[ onOff.text ] (UILabel)**  from 1 to 0 when i push the home button! and actually it perfectly works!  until, I go to second view ("to make some changes") and go back on a main view. after this manipulations (with presentViewController) appDelegate stops influencing on the label :(

so the ***self.viewcontroller.onOff.text=@"O";*** stops assigning the value! this line of code i put into this method "applicationWillResignActive" and as I already mentioned it totally works until i push "setting" button to go to second view and then "back" to first view.

actually I tried some manipulations with unloading the views and I got a hint that
while I pushing a home button to call applicationWillResignActive, it loads second view! on top of the firs, main one...

would be great to have any help with that phantom situation

Comment: Try logging the value of `self.viewcontroller` or `self.viewcontroller.onOff` from your app delegate before setting the value of text.

Comment: i made a method in first viewcontroller that is called from Appdegate and it trigers it but not fully.... actully it calls NSLog line but still leavs my label without attention :((( do not no what to do!

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of your label before setting it? `NSLog(@"%@", self.onOff)`? If so, what does it show? Your view might be unloaded; you could store in your view controller the desired label text and set it in viewDidLoad.